# Nested Loop. Want to print out frame of asterisks

Tags: java

// want to print out a frame of asterisks. The frame must have 16 asterisks as a whole.

```
public class Patterns {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

for(int i=1; i<=4; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=4; i++){
            if((i==1||i==4)&&(j==1||j==4)){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            else{
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            System.out.println();
            }

        }

    } 

}
```

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: When I run it, I don't get the result that I want. it prints out asterisks infintiely

Comment: You increment two times i, change i to j in the second for, and **maybe** it will work.

Comment: Can you show me what you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the if condition -

```
if((i==1||i==4)&&(j==1||j==4)){
 System.out.print("*");
}
```

Better you may try a more robust solution. Here you can adjust your frame height or width by setting `ROW` and `COLUMN`. Using the following code you may print a rectangular frame, for example with `ROW = 15` and `COLUMN = 10`. See the solution here -

```
public class Frame{

    /*You may adjust ROW or COLUMN
    * You may print a rectangular frame
    * by setting ROW = 6 and COLUMN = 12
    */
    private final static int ROW = 4; 
    private final static int COLUMN = 4;

    //Need not to change
    private final static int I_MIN = 1;
    private final static int I_MAX = ROW;
    private final static int J_MIN = 1;
    private final static int J_MAX = COLUMN;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //always start from i=1 and j=1
        for(int i=1; i<=ROW; i++){
            for(int j=1; j<=COLUMN; j++){

                if(isOnMargin(i,j)){
                    System.out.print("*");
                }else{
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }//main()

    /*
    * This method determine whether an (i,j) 
    * is on margin. In main method if an (i,j)
    * on margin then print "*" or print " ".
    */
    private static boolean isOnMargin(int i, int j){

        if(i==I_MIN || i==I_MAX){
            return true;
        }
        else if(j==J_MIN || j==J_MAX){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.

**Output:**
[image: 4x4 frame]

Answer (score 0):

This prints what I call a frame with 16 asterisks:

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
            if(i == 1 || i == 5 || ((i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 4) && (j == 1 || j == 5)))
                System.out.print("*");
            else System.out.print(" ");

         }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that will let you specify the width and height:

```
int width = 5;
int height = 5; 
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == height -1) { //first or last line
            System.out.print("*");
        } else if (j == 0 || j == width -1) { // middle line first or last star
            System.out.print("*"); 
        } else { // middle line not on the edge
            System.out.print(" "); 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(); // start a new line
}
```