# Draw a fence in Java using for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I am tasked to make a fence drawing program.  So far I can have the user input values to set height and width and using nested for loops I can get it to output the height and width as a "#" symbol.  The problem is I need it to have a border of # with | in the middle.

Currently a 4 height 4 width fence looks like this

```
####     
####
####
####
```

I need it to look like this

```
####
#||#
#||#
####


   public void draw() {
       for (i = 1; i < height-1; i++) {
           System.out.print("#");
           for (j = 1; j < width-1; j++) {
               System.out.print("|");
           }
           System.out.println("#");
       }
       fenceCount++;
   }
```

When is it ok to use a break.  I have a loop asking if the user would like to build another fence type y or n.  At the end for the terminating user input "n" does anyone know if there is a better way to do this than a break; ? and is a single break "ok" here?  I have heard breaks are sloppy in loops.  Also I always feel like I have to reverse my thinking on while loops.

Comment: Can you add an example of how a fence is supposed to look to your question (you can put it inside `<pre>`  and `</pre>` tags to make it look as it would look on the console)?

Comment: @alfasin His code compiles rather well on my Eclipse.

Comment: @Alex, You may have a look at this answer. It may be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053675/nested-loop-want-to-print-out-frame-of-asterisks/29054548#29054548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `draw()` to:

```
public void draw() {
    String border = String.format("%0" + width +"d", 0).replace("0", "#");
    System.out.println(border); // top-border
    for (int i = 1; i < height-1; i++) {
        System.out.print("#"); 
        for (int j = 1; j < width-1; j++) {
            System.out.print("|");
        }
        System.out.println("#");
    }
    System.out.println(border); // bottom-border
}
```

Comment: Ah I ran into this with my interest calculator, making a stock border is awesome! I was running into trouble getting the # in there because I've done it in the past for making tables in other program but they are headers with stock words or strings.  String format and replace is genius.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your fence output will currently be entirely filled with '#'
You are right in saying that the top and bottom rows there will be only '#'
For the remaining rows, for the entry in the first and the last column you need a #, else a |

Here is somthing to help:

```
for (i = 1; i <= height; i++)
   {
     if(first or last row)
     {
        for (j = 1; j <= width; j++)
        {
         print#
        }
     }
     else{
           for (j = 1; j <= width; j++)
           {
               if(j=1 or j=last column)
                   print '#'
               else
                   print '|'
           }
         }
      System.out.println();
   }
```

This will build you fence well:-)